# Missing $ inserted error in Latex using matrix in the following latex code:

Tags: math-mode, errors, matrices

```
  \[\begin{bmatrix}
            $ d_1$ & $e_1$ & $0$ & $\cdots$ & $0$\\
            $ c_1$ & $d_2$ & $e_2$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots $\\
            $ 0$ & $\ddots$ & $\ddots$ & $\ddots$ & $0 $\\
            $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\ddots$ & $\ddots$ & $e_N$\\
            $0$ & $\cdots$ & $0$ & $0$ & $c_N$ & $d_N$
            \end{bmatrix}\]
            where $c_i = -1-\frac{h}{2}p(x_i),d_i = 2+h^2q(x_i)\;$ and\; $e_i=-1-\frac{h}{2}p(x_i)$ \\
            \[ \textbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix}
            $-h^{2}r(x_1)+(1+\frac{h}{2}p(x_1))y_0$\\
            $-h^{2}r(x_2)$\\
            $\vdots$\\
            $-h^{2}r(x_{N-1})$\\
            $-h^{2}r(x_N)+(1-\frac{h}{2}p(x_N))y_{N+1}$
            \end{bmatrix}\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! (i) please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, (ii(`matrix` had to be used inside math environment  (iii) all `$` inside `matrix` had to be removed`, (iv) your problem has nothing with Overleaf.

Answer (score 3):

There are several errors in your code. Among the serious ones:

- `\[` and `\]` initiate and terminate an unnumbered displaymath environment. Don't use `$` to initiate and terminate inline math mode when you're already in display math mode. Hence, you must remove all `$` instances inside both `bmatrix` environments.
- `$c_i = -1-\frac{h}{2}p(x_i),d_i = 2+h^2q(x_i)\;$ and\; $e_i=-1-\frac{h}{2}p(x_i)$` is wrong; it should be

  ```
  $c_i = -1-\frac{h}{2}p(x_i)$, $d_i = 2+h^2q(x_i)$, and $e_i=-1-\frac{h}{2}p(x_i)$
  ```

  i.e., you should use three separate inline math groups. Why? There are, syntactically speaking, three separate formulas on that line.
- The final row of the first `bmatrix` environment has a surplus `0 &`.
- The instance of `c_1` in row 2 should be `c_2`, and the instance of `e_N` in the second-to-last row should be `e_{N-1}`, right?
- Not an outright error, but an inaccuracy: Write `\mathbf{b}`, not `\textbf{b}`, while in math mode.
- To make the material look less cramped, I'd replace all four instances of `\frac{h}{2}` with it inline-math equivalent, `(h/2)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' environment
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    d_1 & e_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    c_2 & d_2 & e_2 & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & c_3 & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & d_{N-1} & e_{N-1} \\
    0 & \cdots & 0 & c_N & d_N
\end{bmatrix}
\]
where $c_i = -1-(h/2)p(x_i)$, $d_i = 2+h^2q(x_i)$, and $e_i=-1-(h/2)p(x_i)$.
\[ 
\mathbf{b} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -h^{2}r(x_1)+(1+(h/2)p(x_1))y_0 \\
    -h^{2}r(x_2) \\
    \vdots\\
    -h^{2}r(x_{N-1}) \\
    -h^{2}r(x_N)+(1-(h/2)p(x_N))y_{N+1}  
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks I understand all my mistakes

Answer (score 1):

I guessing that you like to achieve the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \[
\begin{bmatrix}
d_1     & e_1    & 0      & \cdots & 0          \\
c_1     & d_2    & e_2    & \ddots & \vdots     \\
0       & c_2    & \ddots & \ddots   & 0        \\
\vdots  & \ddots & \ddots & \d-{N-1} & e_{N-1}  \\
0       & \cdots & 0      & c_N      & d_N      \\
\end{bmatrix}
    \]
where $c_i = -1-\frac{h}{2}p(x_i)$, $d_i = 2+h^2q(x_i)$ and $e_i=-1-\frac{h}{2}p(x_i)$
    \[
\textbf{b} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    -h^{2}r(x_1)+(1+\frac{h}{2}p(x_1))y_0\\ 
    -h^{2}r(x_2)\\ 
    \vdots\\ 
    -h^{2}r(x_{N-1})\\ 
    -h^{2}r(x_N)+(1-\frac{h}{2}p(x_N))y_{N+1}
\end{bmatrix}
    \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```